# Notation for the geometric quotient of a separated Deligne-Mumford stack?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, notation

Suppose that $X$ is a separated Deligne-Mumford stack, say over a base scheme.

Is there some standard notation for the geometric quotient of $X$? I've tried using $[X]$ but have had complaints.

Comment: Do you mean some sort of course space, good moduli space (in the sense of Alper), or something like that? One standard notation is to denote the stack by $\mathscr X$ or $\mathcal X$ and the scheme by $X$.

Comment: Yes, that is a standard convention, and it works if there is only one stack (``the stack'') in the picture. But it is inconvenient in general. For example, what if I have stacks $\mathcal X$ and $\mathcal Y$, and need to consider the stack $Mor({\mathcal X},{\mathcal Y})$ of morphisms? Or $Bun_G^s$ is often used for a stack of stable $G$-bundles over some variety; must I denote it by $\mathcal{X}$ before taking its geometric quotient?

Comment: You could use $X^c$ maybe?

Comment: How does that work if $X=Bun_G^s$? Do I write $Bun_G^{sc}$? In this context of a group the $sc$ suggests ``simply connected''. Is $(Bun_G^s)^c$ better than $[Bun_G^s]$? And in any case my question was whether there is some standard (that is, already in existence) notation.

Comment: I think $X^c$ or $X^{coarse}$ is quite common. Also, $(Bun^s_G)^s$ seems fine to me. The notation $[X]$ might seem a bit too close to $|X|$ which I think usually denotes the set of points of the stack $X$; see https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04XE